# How to fix Log4j security vulnerability CVE-2021-44228 on SAP Hybris Commerce?

Tags: log4j, sap-commerce-cloud

Severe vulnerability CVE-2021-44228 in Log4j

According to https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228, Apache Log4j <= 2.14.1 JNDI features used in configuration, log messages, and parameters do not protect against attacker controlled LDAP and other JNDI related endpoints.

Commerce Version 1905 and lower use log4j 2.14.x, 2.9.x or lower. As per the recent communication from Apache, to prevent the library being exploited it's urgently recommended that Log4j versions are upgraded (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html) to the latest 2.15 log4j version.

Reference : https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/3130939

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't seem to be a question at all

Comment: Self-answered questions are very welcome here, but the question has to be worded in a way that you would have asked it if you did not know the answer. Could you edit it to be in that fashion?

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest version of log4j jar, the recommended current latest version from SAP response from reference link is 2.15.0

- [log4j-api-2.15.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.15.0)
- [log4j-core-2.15.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.15.0)
- [log4j-jcl-2.15.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jcl/2.15.0)
- [log4j-slf4j-impl-2.15.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.15.0)

Go to platform/ext/core/lib directory and move the log4j jar of older version of the respective packages listed above and replace it with newer onces.

give `ant clean all` and start the servers.

**Additional Notes:**

While trying to replace log4j.jar you might come across any error or warning similar to this log

```
 ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '1203ecdb' at 'null' in 'null'. 
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter). 
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
 log4j:WARN See [http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig][1] for more info.
```

or

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j_init_tomcat.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

The fix is to Remove `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j_init_tomcat.properties` from tomcat options in your local.properties.

Trying ant clean all and start the server again. You should see your server logs now :)

Reference:
https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/3130939

Get to know further about the issue and its alternative workarounds https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/608

> **IMPORTANT** : Please update your solr sever log4j as well!!!

**Edit - Update 1:**

On recent updates from log4j, some vulnerabilities have been identified in 2.15.0 and 2.16.0 as well,

> **!!!! Its recommended to use 2.17.0 version !!!!**

- [log4j-api-2.17.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.17.0)
- [log4j-core-2.17.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.17.0)
- [log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.17.0)
- [log4j-jcl-2.17.0.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jcl/2.17.0)

If you are reading this post on recent vulnerability changes, please check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j for the latest version on the time you read, there might be have been new patches released.

Comment: You should keep just the 2.17 version as log4j creators recommends